# How to show a category to a specific customer group magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Hi my question is how to show particular category products to particular customer group or Business customers. Actually I want to show additional products to only business customer when he gets logged in to his account.

I am usin **Magento 2**

1. I created a customer group.
2. And now I am working on customer group to show products.

Comment: hey @sangan may this can give you some idea that how to do it [https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2](https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2)

Comment: NO still i am not getting how to show some products to specific  customer